# What does the I operator stand for in the context of time series modeling?

Tags: time-series, arima, notation, moving-average

I am reading a paper on parameter estimation for moving-averages, but I'm not exactly sure what the I operator underlined in red stands for. There is no explanation for it anywhere in the paper. Is it the identity matrix?

[image][image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the identity *operator*, $IX_t=X_t$, and is typically used in ARIMA type formulas where you also have the backshift operator $B$ (sometimes people use $\nabla$ for the backshift), or polynomials in $B$. Essentially, it's a way to make notation more compact.

For instance, if you have a time series $(X_t)$, then
$$(I-B)X_t = IX_t-BX_t = X_t-X_{t-1},$$
and
$$(I-B^2)X_t = IX_t-B(BX_t) = X_t-X_{t-2}.$$

Comment: Thanks, any online resources where I can read more about the identity operator? I need to code it into a program and haven't had much luck finding relevant information.

Comment: Well, I don't think there is really much to it. The backshift operator shifts a time series by one lag, but the identity operator simply takes a time series and returns it unchanged. There is really nothing more to it.

Answer (score 7):

The main answer by Stephan is correct, but it is odd to use the identity operator (with the symbol $I$) in a scalar context instead of just using the number one.  It would be simpler here if they just said that:

$$(1-B)X_t = X_t-X_{t-1}.$$

Comment: I think both notations are reasonably common. $1$ is probably a little more prevalent, as in [FPP3](https://otexts.com/fpp3/backshift.html) and in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) (Wikipedia, incidentally, uses $L$ for the backshift operator and calls it a *lag operator*), probably to avoid confusion with the order of integration.

Comment: @Ben In my experience $I$ is more common because $X$ can be a matrix. So it would be the identity matrix in that case.

Comment: Sure, but if there are no other indicators that we are talking about vectors/matrices (e.g., bolding of letters), it seems out of place.